# fresh install 22.04 lts deja dup restore "no backup files found"

Tags: backup, restore, deja-dup

i have a confirmed backup of my old laptop image.

deja dup does recognise the backup hard-drive and folder on fresh install of 22.04 LTS on new laptop..

[image]

but the deja dup on new install says 'no backup found'...

[image: no backups found]

i have read that the default location for deja dup may have to be set to the location of the backup (where the backup is that i want to restore).. but there seems to not be alot of information on this situation i find myself in.

if anyone has a clear and clean method, much appreciated

Comment: Please add more information about your old backup folder location. Is it an external drive? Do you have read and write permission for the folder and read permission for the contents of the folder?

Comment: thank you @user68186 .. always the simple things! I earlier selected the folder in the restore list based on the date, as all listed restore folders had the same name... but going through 'storage selection - local folder - choose folder', as stated on many posts, the restore folders are indeed named and dated differently. For others: I had to go back into my old laptop 'deja-dup - stortage location' to see the exact folder name, and then align this with the correct backup name & date in the list of restore folders on my new laptop deja-dup. then simply select all the folders and hit restore